# Unresolved dependencies NetCDF-Java Library

Tags: java, scala, sbt, netcdf

I am trying to use [NetCDF-Java Library](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/edu.ucar/cdm/4.6.11) in Scala but got

> sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: edu.ucar#cdm;4.6.11: not found

I have already tried manipulate with `sbt.version` (now is set to 1.1.1).
How to use this library in Scala?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library you are looking for was not published to one of the standard repositories SBT uses by default.

It was published to the `boundlessgeo` repository as you can see on the mvnrepository page.

You need to add the repository to the resolution in your build file:

```
resolvers += "boundlessgeo" at "https://repo.boundlessgeo.com/main/"
```